# How to add fields to document that are populated at envelope creation time

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to setup a template that will have a number of fields pre-filled out.  It should behave exactly the way "Full Name" currently does -- I provide the values when creating the envelope and they show up as read-only additions to the document.

I've tried adding "Data Fields" to the document, however there are two problems:

1) When I setup the envelope via API, I try to preset the values (see below for example), but the values do not show up for the signer.  The "" matches what I set the DataField to have.
2) The signer can override those values.

```
"<customFields>"+
            "<textCustomFields>"+
                "<textCustomField>"+
                    "<name>Trip Date</name>"+
                    "<value>Jul 17-21</value>"+
                "</textCustomField>"+
                "<textCustomField>"+
                    "<name>Country</name>"+
                    "<value>Uganda</value>"+
                "</textCustomField>"+
            "</textCustomFields>"+
    "</customFields>"
```

What is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set data fields for your recipients through the API you need to use `textTabs`.  The custom fields that you have referenced are at the envelope level, not the recipient level.

Please go through the [DocuSign Developer Center](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center) as it covers this info.  In particular you should take a look at the **Explore -> Features -> Stick-eTabs** page.  There's a section there called **Data Fields** which answer all your questions:

https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/stick-etabs

You use the `tabLabel` property to pre-populate them and you need to set them in the `tabs` section of your request body.  For instance, if you had 2 data fields (called "Data Field 1" and "Data Field 2") and you wanted to fill them with "foo" and "bar" and you wanted to make them read-only you could use the following JSON.  If you don't want them read-only then set "locked" to "false"...

```
"tabs": {
    "textTabs": [
     {
        "tabLabel": "Data Field 1",
        "value": "foo",
        "locked": "true",
        "xPosition": "200",
        "yPosition": "200",
        "documentId": "1",
        "pageNumber": "1"
    },
    {
        "tabLabel": "Data Field 2",
        "value": "bar",
        "locked": "true",
        "xPosition": "300",
        "yPosition": "200",
        "documentId": "1",
        "pageNumber": "1"
    }]
}
```